# Windows 7 filename restrictions

Tags: windows-7

We're currently rolling out new PCs with Windows 7 Pro. While setting up the despatch company software on a new Windows 7 machine for the warehouse I came across an oddity that I have never struck before. The executable was named `despatch.exe` and whenever I tried to run it as a user it would prompt for an admin logon.

After a lot of stuffing about I discovered that by simply renaming the file it would run fine for the same user account. As `despatch.exe` the file's icon had a shield on it. After renaming it the shield disappeared. It also made no difference whether the file was located on a network share or on the local machine. On Win XP and Server 2003 the file works and looks the same either way.

Has anyone come across other "protected" filenames such as this that might cause us problems with Windows 7. I've tried Googling for this information but have not yet found anything relevant. The last thing I want to do is give users elevated privileges to work around such issues.

Comment: the despatch application is it a stand alone .exe or an installed application? if stand alone it could be the file needs to be unblocked in the properties of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that at least in windows 2003, a DNS entry of iscsi wouldn't work for a machine I was setting up for testing iscsi.  The host just failed to be found in dns.. couldn't for the life of me figure it out until I changed it to iscsi1 or something...

There are some random things in there, just the nature of the business of software...  Reserved words, etc.  I'm not sure you're gonna find a list - just some other people mentioning something similar but maybe not remembering specifics...    :)